# Error: Cannot find module '/dmitrich0/frontend/src/app/npm run start'. DOCKER

Tags: angular, typescript, docker, build, nest

I'm getting these errors when trying to docker-compose up:

> Error: Cannot find module '/dmitrich0/frontend/src/app/npm run start'
> real-time-chat-nestjs-angular-frontend-1        |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
> real-time-chat-nestjs-angular-frontend-1        |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
> real-time-chat-nestjs-angular-frontend-1        |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)
> real-time-chat-nestjs-angular-frontend-1        |     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
> real-time-chat-nestjs-angular-frontend-1        |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
> real-time-chat-nestjs-angular-frontend-1        |   requireStack: []
> real-time-chat-nestjs-angular-frontend-1        | }

> Error: Cannot find module '/dmitrich0/src/app/npm run start:dev'
> real-time-chat-nestjs-angular-api-1             |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
> real-time-chat-nestjs-angular-api-1             |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
> real-time-chat-nestjs-angular-api-1             |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)
> real-time-chat-nestjs-angular-api-1             |     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
> real-time-chat-nestjs-angular-api-1             |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
> real-time-chat-nestjs-angular-api-1             |   requireStack: []
> real-time-chat-nestjs-angular-api-1             | }

API Dockerfile:

```
############################
#########DEVELOPMENT########
############################
FROM node:14 AS development
WORKDIR /dmitrich0/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000

############################
#########PRODUCTION#########
############################
FROM node:14 AS production
ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
WORKDIR /dmitrich0/src/app
COPY --from=development /dmitrich0/src/app .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

Front dockerfile:

```
############################
#########DEVELOPMENT########
############################
FROM node:14 AS development
WORKDIR /dmitrich0/frontend/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 4200

############################
#########PRODUCTION#########
############################
FROM node:14 AS production
ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
WORKDIR /dmitrich0/src/app
COPY --from=development /dmitrich0/src/app .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  api:
    volumes:
      - ./api:/dmitrich0/src/app
      - /dmitrich0/src/app/node_modules
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./api
      target: development
    command:
      - npm run start:dev
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://user:password@postgres:5432/db
      NODE_ENV: development
      PORT: 3000
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "9229:9229"
  frontend:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./frontend
      target: development
    command:
      -  npm run start
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/dmitrich0/frontend/src/app
      - /dmitrich0/frontend/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    links:
      - api
```

First time working with Docker. What can I do with this errors?

Tried to change paths in volumes, but I don't understand why there are modules 'npm run start:dev' and 'npm run start'.

It's just that the paths are written incorrectly somewhere, or I made a mistake that it's hard for me to guess now, because I haven't worked with Docker before.

Comment: I removed the data about postgres and postgresadmin from the file, do not pay attention to the information about the database.

Comment: you should use `nginx` for serving `angular` build. [here](https://dev.to/oneofthedevs/docker-angular-nginx-37e4) is a guide.

Answer (score 0):

In the same way that there are two syntaxes for a Dockerfile `RUN` directive, a Compose [`command:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#command) can either be a string or a list of words.  If it's a string, Compose uses a simplistic splitting algorithm and doesn't automatically run a shell; if it's a list then Compose uses that list of words directly without doing any further processing.

You're using a YAML list

```yaml
command:
  - npm run start
# ^   on a second line, with a list marker
```

and so this is processed as a single word, much as if you ran `'npm run start'` from an interactive shell.

The easy fix is to change this from a list to a string

```yaml
command: npm run start
```

The specific error you're getting is because the `node` image has some complex logic in its entrypoint wrapper to let you `docker run node index.js` without repeating the `node` interpreter command.  If you pass it something that's an actual command `docker run node npm ...` then it runs it, but if the first word of the command isn't a command, it's run via `node`.  So you're getting the equivalent of `node 'npm run start'` which produces those errors.

(Another approach that's worth considering, especially for a front-end application, is starting the back-end in a container `docker-compose up -d api` and then using Node directly on the host system for routine development.  This would let you delete the unnecessary multi-stage build and the subtle `volumes:` setup.)